# how to use a variable of one class in another in php

Tags: php, oop

i made a class named db for connecting to server

```
class db {

      private $host='localhost';
      private $username='root';
      private $password='';
      private $dbc;

    public function connect() {
           $this->dbc=mysql_connect_db($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);
    }
```

and in index.php I created an object of class 'db'

```
$con=new db;
$con->connect();
```

and the problem is that I made a query by

```
 mysql_query($query,"host connection parameter");
```

and i don't know how to pass the second parameter for mysql_query() which is a host connection parameter.i tried typing

```
mysql_query($query,$con->connect()->dbc);
```

but it did'nt work.do any one know how to fix this

Comment: I´m sorry but this class is so useless and badly designed, that you would be better of using mysql_connect. If you just want to use OOP style why don´t you use MySQLi or PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your class like this so you can execute queries with it.

```
class db {

  private $host='localhost';
  private $username='root';
  private $password='';
  private $dbc;

public function connect() {
       $this->dbc=mysql_connect_db($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);
}

public function query($sql) {
      return mysql_query($sql, $this->dbc);
}
```

then you can use

```
$db = new db();  
   $db->connect();
   $rs = $db->query("SELECT .....");
```